# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_rows'

Tags: python, pandas

While reading from pandas read_csv method, encountered the error - keyword argument 'max rows'

Code :

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('./data.csv')
data.head()
```

Error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
    344             if method is not None:
--> 345                 return method()
    346             return None
    347         else:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _repr_html_(self)
    694     @Substitution(shared_params=fmt.common_docstring, returns=fmt.return_docstring)
    695     def to_string(
--> 696         self,
    697         buf=None,
    698         columns=None,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in to_html(self, buf, columns, col_space, header, index, na_rep, formatters, float_format, sparsify, index_names, justify, bold_rows, classes, escape, max_rows, max_cols, show_dimensions, notebook, decimal, border, table_id)
   2035             Default is latin-1. Unicode is not supported.
   2036         byteorder : str
-> 2037             Can be ">", "<", "little", or "big". default is `sys.byteorder`.
   2038         time_stamp : datetime
   2039             A datetime to use as file creation date.  Default is the current

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in to_html(self, classes, notebook, border)
    751         else:
    752             nrows = len(self.frame)
--> 753 
    754         str_lst = []
    755         st = 0

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_rows'
```

Need help on resolving the issue.

Comment: what version of pandas and ipykernel are installed?

Comment: pandas : '0.23.3'
, ipykernel : 4.4.0

Comment: my gut says something is broken in your environment. If it's an option it might be worth installing a newer version of python (3.8 or 3.9) and installing a newer version of pandas (1.*) in a fresh virtual environment.

Comment: Thanks, Resolved after upgrading to pandas version : '0.25.1' and ipykernel version : 5.1.2

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade pandas and restart kernel worked for me:

```
!pip install --upgrade pandas==[version]
```

on Jupyter notebook( !, provided by Jupyter, allows shell commands to be run within cells ).

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

pd.options.display.max_rows = 9999

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

print(data.head)
```

- Hope this will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: Tried with pd.options.display.max_rows = 99 also, unfortunately it did'nt worked

Comment: @KhileshChauhan Try to run on different IDE. I'm using Pycharm, no error found.

Comment: Thanks, Resolved after upgrading to pandas version : '0.25.1' and ipykernel version : 5.1.2