# Error while saving pd.DataFrame to csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this error when I'm trying to save csv

```
df.to_csv('./df.csv', index=False)
```

And the error

```
TypeError: CSVFormatter.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'line_terminator'
```

versions of libs:

- ipywidgets==8.0.2
- pandas [required: Any, installed: 1.5.0]

UPD: after restarting kernel everything is working. Why can it happened?

Comment: [Does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71369078/init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-max-rows)

Comment: No it doesn't unfortunately

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.